# Spring security list all @PreAuthorize protected urls

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application that uses Spring MVC and Spring Security. We annotate controller methods with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole([role]")` annotations to ensure that user has given role in order to call any method.

So for example we might have a Edit method exposed at "/edit" which requires the user to have admin role. This works well with the PreAuthorize annotation.

In order to show Edit button on the UI, we end up duplicating the authorization information on UI. I would like to avoid this. Is there way in spring security that allows me to check if a user is authorized for a certain url (other than obviously calling that url :)

Comment: @dur I don't mind calling a server URL, however on the UI I would not like to show the Edit button. I could call this in advance when the screen loads, but I will need to pass data to it which I dont have.

Comment: @RajindRuparathna that would be duplicating the authorization defn on the UI, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @6ton: Yes. Agreed. However, I don't see a way around duplicating the permissions in the front end for your requirement. It's an interesting problem. Let us know if you find a solution.

Comment: @dur That would work only if I could avoid the actual method call to edit. I could call the edit URL with the data it requires, however that will end up actually editing the data.

Comment: That's right. You could also write a second endpoint (maybe as HTTP `OPTIONS`), which makes nothing else as check the authentication, returns 403 or 200. Your have to annotate the second endpoint in the same way as the first endpoint.